# Firebase ValueListener is telling me that a node does not exist

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am sorry if I'm missing something but I've been at it for the last couple of hours. A node clearly exists in my Firebase database but the listener attached to it refuses to believe so.

**JSON tree**

```
"liveSessions" : {
"-KaOX9bL9dbNOY0iSHP7" : {
  "latitude" : 24.8763847,
  "location" : {
    ".priority" : "tkrtw2s56n",
    "g" : "tkrtw2s56n",
    "l" : [ 24.8763847, 67.0771205 ]
  },
  "longitude" : 67.0771205,
  "participantLimit" : 20,
  "sessionCreatedBy" : "test notifications",
  "sessionCreatedByKey" : "MeIPeBAvKOWwDc2BFz97XbWmgzJ2",
  "sessionDuration" : "7:20:00",
  "sessionImgUri" : url,
  "sessionSportType" : "Throwball",
  "sportIconIdName" : "throwball",
  "timeStampCreated" : -1484339604568,
  "usersRequesting" : {
    "moO4LEDl0MVQufW6UFBRkywsYyE3" : "moO4LEDl0MVQufW6UFBRkywsYyE3"
  }
}
}
```

**Java Code**

```
public class ManageLiveSessionFragment extends Fragment {

String sessionKey;

ArrayList<String> requestedUserList;
ArrayList<String> joinedUserList;

RecyclerView requestedUsersRecycler;

DatabaseReference sessionRef;
private SessionRequestedUsersAdapter sessionRequestedUsersAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manage_live_session, container, false);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    sessionKey = bundle.getString("SESSION_KEY");
    Log.d("sessionKey", sessionKey);

    sessionRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    requestedUserList = new ArrayList<>();
    joinedUserList = new ArrayList<>();

    requestedUsersRecycler = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.manageSession_requesting);
    requestedUsersRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    sessionRequestedUsersAdapter = new SessionRequestedUsersAdapter(requestedUserList, getContext(), sessionKey);
    requestedUsersRecycler.setAdapter(sessionRequestedUsersAdapter);

    sessionRef.child("liveSessions").child(sessionKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                Log.d("Does it exist?", "nope");
            }
            for (DataSnapshot user : dataSnapshot.child("usersRequesting").getChildren()){
                requestedUserList.add(user.getKey());
                Log.d("Added", "One user added");
                sessionRequestedUsersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Debugging the code just shows that the node (the snapshot of it) doesn't exist.

Comment: Two options I can think of: is your `sessionKey` value correct? Alternatively: are you using disk persistence? If so, the disk cache might have an old value for the node (or in this case a non-value) and `onDataChange` might fire twice: once for the cached non-value and once (later, when you're online) for the actual value.

Comment: This is the session key copy-pasted directly from the Android Monitor: "KaOX9bL9dbNOY0iSHP7"
I'm not using disk persistence.

Comment: Oh dang, I figured it out. the sessionKey is missing a character.

Comment: Good to hear you found it. When code I wrote doesn't give the output I expect, I tend to mistrust my expectation - not my code. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To reach the usersRequesting node, you should use something like this :

```
sessionRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
.child("liveSessions")
.child("usersRequesting")
.addValueEventListener( ... );
```

Give us an example of sessionKey

There's the error.
At node .child(sessionKey), the rest of JSON Tree will be :

```
"-KaOX9bL9dbNOY0iSHP7" : {
  "latitude" : 24.8763847,
  "location" : {
    ".priority" : "tkrtw2s56n",
    "g" : "tkrtw2s56n",
    "l" : [ 24.8763847, 67.0771205 ]
  }
```

which, obviously, is no usersRequesting node

Try my example at the beginning of the post

Comment: This is the sessionKey copied exactly from the Android Monitor: KaOX9bL9dbNOY0iSHP7

Comment: That's just a fault in my formatting. I figured the problem out anyway. the sessionKey value in my code is missing a character.

Comment: The tree shown to us is also bad formatted, since in sessionKey is no usersRequesting node

Comment: Yeah, that's what I said